# codec encoding video efficiency test in webrtc

Tags: browser, encoding, webrtc, benchmarking, frame-rate

I would like to build automatic tool that will test encoding efficiency on enter website. I'm using webrtc for video streaming and some users with weaker hardware experiencing problems with encoding efficiency. So ideally I would like to measure how the device behaves respectively with vp9, vp8 and h.264 encoding and choose that which will ensure smmoth stream and highest quality. I build simple tool that measures frames per second and resolution in each codec, but it seems that it is not the best measurement - webrtc manages resolution on it's own, sometimes keeps lowers resolution and more stable fps, but it is not always the case, it's quite unpredictable on older computers. I have another idea to make some benchmark, but I'm not sure if it's possible to make meaningful measurement in a few seconds (I don't want user wait too long). And it's problematic to measure cpu usage from website. What's the best approach for this? I would be grateful for some advices, I'm not very advanced in webrtc and maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to measure *decoding* / playback, not encoding.  (Also, "encoding efficiency" would normally refer to things like quality per bitrate, or encoding speed.)

Comment: The problem I want to prevent is that person, who is broadcasting video with weak cpu couldn't be able to produce for example 30fps because of encoding takes too much time. I would like to use vp8/vp9 by default to provide highest quality, but I would like to detect cpu problems and switch encoding to h264 in this case because it has hardware acceleraion in many cases, so it can partially solve the problem